# Url friendly with two parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im having an issue here with my url that looks like this

```
 www.mywebsite.com/chat.php?room=12&name=some-name
```

i want it to be like that

```
 www.mywebsite.com/chat/12/some-name
```

what i have tried is

```
 RewriteEngine On

# new rule to handle example.com/blah123/sys
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:chat\.php)?\?room=([^\s]+)&name=([^\s]+)? [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /chat/%1/%2? [R=301]
```

But this gives me

```
  www.mywebsite.com/1/my-room      //without chat/
```

i have looked other other solutions but no one helped me

thanks for the help.

Comment: im hoping your help :) @anubhava !

Answer (score 0):

You must capture the relevant parts of the request URL and use it in [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)s substitution

```
RewriteRule ^chat/(.+?)/(.+)$ /chat.php?room=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: should i clear my history ? because it gives same result as mine in my question

Comment: You tested with `R=301`, permanent redirect. Restarting your browser should be sufficient.

Comment: ok i did try it in firefox instead of clearing or closing my chrome , but it didnt change anything , same url it gives this `www.mywebsite.com/chat.php?room=12&name=some-name`

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess? Or did you add an `R` flag?

Comment: R flag? where ?  i have some rules before this

Comment: But the rules are not about chat.php

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Where R flag this ?

Comment: I meant, if you added the R flag to my rule.

Comment: No i havnt commented your rule.